# Show that the relation "is subformula of" is transitive

Tags: logic

I'm reading Dirk van Dalen's Logic and Structure and I don't know how to approach it.
Do I have to do induction, and if I have, induction in what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref. [van Dalen, page 12](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA12) for the definition of *sub-formula*:

> if $\varphi$ is *atomic*, then $\text {Sub}(\varphi) = \{ \varphi \}$,

and the obvious part dealing with connectives, like e.g. $\lor$:

> $\text {Sub}(\varphi \lor \psi) = \text {Sub}(\varphi) \cup \text {Sub}(\psi) \cup \{ \varphi \lor \psi \}$.

What we have to prove is that:

> if $\varphi$ is a sub-f of $\psi$ and $\psi$ is a sub-f of $\sigma$, then $\varphi$ is a sub-f of $\sigma$.

The fact is quite obvious; consider the case: $\lor$.

If $\sigma=\sigma_1 \lor \sigma_2$, then  $\text {Sub}(\sigma_i) \subseteq \text {Sub}(\sigma)$, for $i=1,2$ by definition.

Thus, if $\psi \in \text {Sub}(\sigma_i)$, then $\psi \in \text {Sub}(\sigma)$.

---

But yes, we can consider it an application of [induction on the *complexity* of $\sigma$ (page 8)](https://books.google.it/books?id=u0wlXPHATDcC&pg=PA8), adding the trivial case of $\sigma$ *atomic*, where $\varphi=\psi=\sigma$.

Comment: Thank you! Regarding of your edit: I still don't understand where should I use induction, and in this case, induction on what?  (I´m sorry if ¨induction on what¨ doesn´t mean anything, I´m not a native english speacker, but what I try to say is that when there is an induction proof in $ \N $, the is induction on n, so in the thesis there is n+1. In this case, it's in $\sigma, \psi  $or$  \phi$?)

Comment: @Impropio - see [Structural induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_induction).